# Magento 1.7: Error create order for quote #15: ProductId is required for OrderItem

Tags: checkout

Just recently started getting this error sent via email when trying to place an order in store. done some searching around and cannot seem to find anything about it.

I'm assuming that somewhere in the database the quote number is not incrementing as each time i place the order, it comes up with quote #15?

Comment: Error does not look like a core exception. I assume you may be using some extension related to sales order section, which may cause this issue. What I feel here is, product id is not set to an order item while magento tries to convert a quote into an order. In order to further help, you need to provide more details

Comment: I don't really have any more details. nothing in the error logs beside when trying to purchase something after the paypal  details enter it comes up with "unable to initialize express checkout" it is also doing the same thing with Credit card payments.

Comment: Seem to be a database corruption in the end, just restored it and all is good now.

Comment: Happy to hear it.